# center image in a div

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm trying to center horizontally an image in a div, and i don't understand why it isn't working... I've centered images so many times, and this time i just don't understand...
Here is what i've tried...

CSS

```
#cabeca{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 290px;
margin: auto;
}

.cabecasize {
width:100%;
min-width: 968px;
height:auto;
min-height: 290px;
overflow:hidden;
left:0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}

.cabecafundo{
position: absolute;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
background-color: black;
height: 100%;
top:0;
z-index: -1;
}

.overcabeca{
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="cabeca">
    <div class="overcabeca">
        <img src="images/av61.png" alt="av61" class="cabecasize" />
    </div>
    <div class="cabecafundo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas??

Comment: everything is working the way it should... except the image, it just doesn't want to stay centered... It is already in a centered div, but when the page shrinks, an overflow happens and the img stay fixed, when it should go with the overflow and keep centered... thank for the help everybody!

Comment: Why are you giving the image a width of 100%? Because you're basically telling the image to fill it's parent

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld I need it to fill the parent, but i also have min-width, so that it stays the size I want... the size right now is perfect, i just need it to be in the center of the div (when the parent is smaller than 968px)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld No the same... the solution there work for smaller inner divs... my inner div when I need it to be centered is bigger than the parent with overflow happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below code, I hope it will helps you.

```css
.wrap{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
.midImg{
  margin: auto;  
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/473506797462896640/_M0JJ0v8.png" alt="av61" class="midImg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add this css to your image

```
img{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
.image {
  text-align: center;
  background: #c0c0c0;
  border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;

}

.image:before {
  content: '\200B';
/*   content: '';
  margin-left: -0.25em; */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
 }

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
   }
```

---

```
<div class="image" style="height: 600px;">
    <div class="centered">
        <img src="download.jpg"  alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```